# How to return all available system Timezones in GMT

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios5, nstimezone

I want to use All Available system TimeZones in GMT Format like

```
(GMT+5:00)chennai,Mumbai,Kolkata NewDelhi
```

Any one can help?

Comment: All time zones have same value. And if they have different values you cant expect a single date to follow all.

Comment: I have an option as "Select TimeZone" . In that I want to use available timezones but i want that all in GMT Format.

Comment: only of india or of world?

Comment: I can get the systemTimeZone Names using [NSTimeZone knownTimeZoneNames]  but it is not in the GMT Format

Comment: Then you can convert all timezones by adding and subtracting its offset to find relative in GMT.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following lines of code.

```
NSArray *timeZoneNames = [NSTimeZone knownTimeZoneNames];
for(NSString *stringName in timeZoneNames) {
    NSTimeZone *timeZoneTemp = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:stringName];
    NSLog(@"%@", [timeZoneTemp description]);
}
```

Comment: She knows that, she need all in GMT not all the timezones avaliable see the comment.

Comment: TIMEZONES Africa/Abidjan (GMT) offset 0
TIMEZONES Africa/Accra (GMT) offset 0
TIMEZONES Africa/Addis_Ababa (EAT) offset 10800
TIMEZONES Africa/Algiers (CET) offset 3600

Comment: Oh! Sorry, i misunderstood your question, some experts here sure will help you.

Comment: My answer will give the output. Africa/Johannesburg (GMT+02:00) offset 7200 Africa/Juba (GMT+03:00) offset 10800

Comment: No i get the result as Africa/Addis_Ababa (EAT) offset 10800 ... what may be the problem?

Comment: What is your region format in Settings->General->International->Region Format?

Comment: I am using mac "I have check selected Show all regions"

Answer (score 0):

First store all the timezones as :

```
NSArray *timezoneNames = [NSTimeZone knownTimeZoneNames];
NSMutableArray *timezones = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[timezoneNames count]];
for (NSString *name in [timezoneNames sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)]){
    [(NSMutableArray *)timezones addObject:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:name]];
}
NSLog(@"All timezones :\n%@",timezones);
```

Then you can convert all timezones by adding and subtracting its offset to find relative to GMT.

Comment: I am not sure about TimeZone.. Can u Expalin in detail